# How to move specific rows of column 1 to a specific position of column 2 in the dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic-columns

```
 employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope', '20000', '30000' ,'40000')
 startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
 kick<-1:9

cbind.fill <- function(...){
nm <- list(...) 
nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
    rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
} 

employ.data<- data.frame(cbind.fill(employee, kick, startdate))
```

Following will be the result.

```
employ.data
           X1   X2    X3
       John Doe  1   14914
     Peter Gynn  2   13963
     Jolie Hope  3   13586
          20000  4  <NA>
          30000  5  <NA>
          40000  6  <NA>
           <NA>  7  <NA>
           <NA>  8  <NA>
           <NA>  9  <NA>
```

Now, I am trying the move the names in the second column and the second column numbers into third column. Such that, the result comes out as following

```
       X1       X2        X3
       John Doe 20000     4
     Peter Gynn 30000     5
     Jolie Hope 40000     6
          <NA>    1     14914
          <NA>    2     13586 
          <NA>    3     13586
          <NA>    7     <NA>
          <NA>    8     <NA>
          <NA>    9     <NA>
```

I have been trying to do this since last couple of days but to no avail I am getting error messages. Here is one of my trial

```
      rbind.fill(employ.data[c(4:6),1], employ.data[c(1:3),2]) 
      rbind.fill(employ.data[c(4:6),2], employ.data[c(1:3),3])
    Error:  All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense? Why are the numbers in the employee vector in the first place? I'm having a hard time finding any logical reason to expect the desired output you've shown given the input values.

Comment: This is just an example data set. My data set includes only numbers. But I want to see how something like this can be done so that I will be able to apply that to my dataframe in R. If you want, you can also use numbers instead of employee names

Comment: Is it possible to turn original dataframe with 3 columns into one column so that data from column 3 is after data from column 2 and the data from column is is one top. Then we can slice the data however we want and use the cbind.fill function to get the same result. This is dirty method but it might be effective

Comment: I'm away from my cpu but use unlist(employ. data). As one long vector, it will be easier to work with. You could then concatenate with c() however many NAs you need. it will then 'push' the values over to where you need. `x <- unlist(employ. data);y <- c(x[1:4], rep(NA, 6), x[5:length(x)])`. Then turn y back into a data frame.